# How to filter django queryset for whole numbers (DecimalField)

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a queryset with `amount` (`DecimalField(decimal_places=2)`) fields. I want to filter the queryset to exclude any rows with amounts that are not integer (whole number) values.

Example valid values: `1.00`, `125.00`

Example invalid values: `0.99`, `14.01`

Is there any function that would allow me to do something like:

```
qs = qs.filter(amount=floor(F('amount')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can make use of the [**`Floor`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#floor):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Floor

qs.filter(amount=Floor('amount'))
```

For recent Django versions, you can implement this function yourself, like it is implemented in [Django-2.2 [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/db/models/functions/math.py#L92):

> ```
> class Floor(Transform):
>     function = 'FLOOR'
>     lookup_name = 'floor'
> ```